# From BIM model to Unity for VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, revit-api, fbx, bim

Is there any method or aproach,apart from bruteforce(doing everything by hand) to get a BIM model from Revit into Unity's FBX without any details concerning the number of polygons? For example: theres a lot of office furniture that has a lot of details on each and every one of them(probably Ikea models) so I want to simplify everything and get the lowest poly possible of each chair,table,laptop there is. Another,maybe more important, example is when there are walls of different types that might have a lot of details on them cause its important for BIM Managers and other, but for me in Unity that wall or whatever could be a simple cube or a cilynder or some other primitive form. So in a nutshell is there any way to do this apart from taking every wall,every chair and every whatever and maunualy replacing them with a low poly alternative?

I am asking this because I should develop a VR experiance and Headsets can only go to up about 500k polygones and that's pushing it.

Comment: I see lots of interesting options just searching for [revit unity](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=revit+unity). For total control, of course, you would have to DIY.